# Delphi xe3 Mainform hide

Tags: forms, delphi, hide, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I have been trying to start my application with hiden main form, but no luck. It 
compiles and everything, but when I run it I get runtime error. When I use timer and set it to 1 millisecond and then call `Application.MainForm.Hide` it hides but it flashes i dont want that to happen

```
program Project1;
uses
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.MainForm.Visible := false;
  Form1.Visible:=false;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: "i get runtime error" is absolutely meaningless if you don't tell us what the runtime error is. When posting, please remember that we can't see your screen or read your mind, and so you need to be **specific** and provide the details here in your question. If you don't give us the information to use to help you, we can't be of much help. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a FireMonkey application the Auto-created forms (are created) and the `MainForm` property is assigned in the `Application.Run` method. So the access violation is caused because the `MainForm` property and `form1` variable is nil.

In order to access such properties you must execute the [`RealCreateForms`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.RealCreateForms) method first

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form1);
  Application.RealCreateForms;
  //Application.MainForm.Left:=-Application.MainForm.Width;
  Application.MainForm.Visible:=False;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Related answer with caveat mentining different platforms https://stackoverflow.com/a/34977674/77764

Answer (score 0):

Much easier method - override CanShow:

```
type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
  public
    function CanShow: Boolean; override;
  end;

...

function TfrmMain.CanShow: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False; // Or return True when it's OK to show
end;
```