# Can't set Fire Monkey Form property

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to initialize form properties in the program source file in a Fire Monkey application and it throws an exception.  Here is the code:

```
uses
    System.StartUpCopy,
    FMX.Forms,
    uMainForm in 'Units\uMainForm.pas' {MainForm},
    UDataModule in 'Units\UDataModule.pas' {DataMod: TDataModule},
    DataHelperClasses in 'Units\DataHelperClasses.pas',
    EXDIntf in 'Units\EXDIntf.pas',
    Exd in 'Units\Exd.pas';

    {$R *.res}
    var
      ViewModel: TEXDViewModel;
    begin
      Application.Initialize;
      Application.CreateForm(TDataMod, DataMod);
      Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
      ViewModel := TEXDViewModel.Create;
      MainForm.Data := DataMod;
      MainForm.ViewModel := ViewModel;  //This throws an access violation exception
      ViewModel.Data := DataMod;
     Application.Run;
end.
```

I have no problem doing this in a VCL app.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

There is difference in behavior between VCL and FMX - FireMonkey `Application.CreateForm` method. While in VCL `CreateForm` actually creates form and after that call form variable is fully initialized and ready to be used, in FMX `CreateForm` does not create form and form variable would still be uninitialized - `nil` - after that call. Because of that using form variable throws AV.

[FMX.TApplication.CreateForm](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.CreateForm)

> CreateForm does not create the given form immediately. It just adds a
>   request to the pending list. RealCreateForms creates the real forms.

FMX has `Application.RealCreateForms` method that is automatically called in `Application.Run`. If you need to use form variables before that, you can call `Application.RealCreateForms` yourself. After that call you can safely use form variables you added to the list with `Application.CreateForm`

Keep in mind that `Application.RealCreateForms` will go through form creation process only once, so you have to call it **after** you made **all calls** to `Application.CreateForm` or you will end up with some unitialized forms.

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TDataMod, DataMod);
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);

  // this forces creation of FireMonkey forms
  Application.RealCreateForms;
  ....
```

---

**Note**: On Windows and OSX platforms `RealCreateForms` is first thing that is called in `Application.Run`, so it does not matter whether it is called by you or automatically. However, on Android and iOS platforms additional (initialization) logic happens before `RealCreateForms` is called in `Application.Run`, if you develop for those platforms, you should proceed with caution when using `RealCreateForms` and watch for potential side-effects. Probably the best option for mobile platforms would be to move your custom initialization into Form `OnCreate` event.

Comment: By default, `RealCreateForms()` is called inside of `Application.Run()`.

Comment: If that is correct answer please accept it. [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Are there downsides to calling `Application.RealCreateForms` before `Application.Run`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Now that you have mentioned it, there are no downsides on Windows and OSX because, RealCreateForms is called immediately in Application.Run. However, on iOS and Android there are some other initializations in place before RealCreateForms is called so there may be downsides.